# How to cast the List<object> to List<T>?

Tags: c#

I am struggling to fix the following problem:

I have list of object and object type is int:

```
int a = 1;
  int b = 2;
  int c = 3;
  List<object> kk = new List<object>( );
  kk.Add( ( object )a );
  kk.Add( ( object )b );
  kk.Add( ( object )c );
```

and I want to cast the `List<object>` to `List<objecttype>` and in above example object type is int. I want to cast `List<object>` to `List<int>`. Is there a way address this problem?

I am looking for generic solution and assume no knowledge of casting type.

[image]

Comment: `List<int> l = kk.Select(k=> (int)k).ToList();`

Comment: I also want you to realise that this I believe will incur boxing/unboxing penalties.

Comment: @Fendy While that works, I'd only use such a long form when I have kk typed as like `List<long>` and wish to get a `List<int>` out .. (That code is equivalent to `kk.Cast<int>().ToList()` *when* kk is typed as `List<object>`.)

Comment: if list of object will have string then this casting will not work and should i have to try to cast as string, int, bool and double and return the successfully completed casting list.

Comment: @User1551892 If the list has string/long/int/bool values and the goal is to get the values converted to ints as best as possible, then should say so in the question - it's a different answer. If the goal is to get "only the ints", then see OfType in the answers.

Comment: @user2246674: I mentioned in my question two things:                 1-I want to cast the List<object> to List<objecttype> and in above example object type is int                                           2-I am looking for generic solution and assume no knowledge of casting type.

Comment: Such is not obvious at all in the question and showing example data of all ints is a very poor choice to draw out appropriate answers to *that* question/problem. Consider updating the question and example input/output to reflect the real goals. However, keep in mind that `List<int>` is a *compile time type* and thus *cannot* be inferred from (or dependent upon) the *runtime values* in `List<object>` - the information simply isn't accessible until later when it is too late to use.

Comment: With the change in title, look up [`TypeConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter.aspx). It can be used to convert between two arbitrary types, provided such a conversion is known/possible .. and note that `T` *still doesn't come* from the type of the objects in `List<object>`. It's a similar problem of knowing `T->int` (based only off of `List<object>`) as it is knowing of `List<object>->List<int>`. The values simply cannot be used until runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   var typeofkk = kk.ToArray( ).Select( x => x.GetType( ) ).ToArray( ).FirstOrDefault( );
   Array ll = Array.CreateInstance( typeofkk, kk.Count );
   Array.Copy( kk.ToArray (), ll, kk.Count );
```

perhaps, this is not the solution which I was looking for but somehow it solved my problem.

Answer (score 20):

Two ways to do it with linq

This version will throw if any of the objects aren't `int`.

```
var ints = kk.Cast<int>().ToList();
```

This version will leave you only the ones that CAN be cast to `int`.

```
var ints = kk.OfType<int>().ToList();
```

Comment: Note: The methods only handle *direct casts*, and neither method supports implicit/explicit conversions. (This can lead to confusing behavior sometimes. There are some good SO posts on it.)

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you could try something like this:

```
List<object> objects = new List<object>();
List<int> ints = objects.Select(s => (int)s).ToList();
```

Should work for all types.

So in general:

```
List<object> objects = new List<object>();
List<objecttype> castedList = objects.Select(s => (objecttype)s).ToList();
```

Comment: Real world example: 


grdDetailList.GetRows().Where(x => (int) x.Cells["TreasuryDetailLedgerID"].Value == treasuryID).ToList()

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var newList = kk.Cast<int>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.Cast<int>()` on your list, `kk`.

Comment: You just used VB.Net syntax for a C# question ;)

Comment: I did; I fell into autonomous mode... :'(

Your answer is better anyway ;)